# How can I make the value XPathSelectElement same as the original copy

Tags: c#, html, xpath

I already have a code that will get the value of the tag head, the problem is the in the original the special character is converted in hexa while the value the xpathselectelement value get is already converted in utf8. How can i make the value XPathSelectElement get the same as original.

Here is my code:

```
if (content.Contains("<h1"))
            {
                _chapterName = inputXDoc.XPathSelectElement("//h1").Value;
            }
            else if (content.Contains("<h2"))
            {
                _chapterName = inputXDoc.XPathSelectElement("//h2").Value;
            }
            else if (content.Contains("<h3"))
            {
                _chapterName = inputXDoc.XPathSelectElement("//h3").Value;
            }
            else if (content.Contains("<h4"))
            {
                _chapterName = inputXDoc.XPathSelectElement("//h4").Value;
            }
```

Here is the html the value came from:

```
<h1><a id="p85"/><a id="ch10" href="005_inhoud.html#ch10">10. &#x2018;Ben je nu gezond?&#x2019;</a></h1>
```

The output of the input XPathSelectElement("//h1").Value;

## 10. ‘Ben je nu gezond?’

The output what I want is here:

```
10. &#x2018;Ben je nu gezond?&#x2019;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're parsing the file using an XML-parser, character entities (‘ etc.) automatically are converted to actual characters while loading the XML into the DomDocument.

If you want to keep the entities themselves, you can pre-process the document to double escape the ampersand.

```
&#x2018;Ben je nu gezond?&#x2019;
```

needs to become

```
&amp;#x2018;Ben je nu gezond?&amp;#x2019;
```

The text in the source code (in the DomDocument) will be like

```
&#x2018;Ben je nu gezond?&#x2019;
```

Ik hoop dat deze oplossing voor jou werkbaar is!